# Chromeの拡張"Edit with Emacs`でEmacsを開くと別ウィンドウに開いてしまう

Tags: emacs

Chrome拡張の`Edit with Emacs`を使っているのですが、標準では既存のウィンドウではなく新しくウィンドウを開いてしまうみたいなのですが、既に開いているEmacsがある場合はそちらに新しいバッファを開く動作にすることはできますか？

設定にChroniumOSを使ってる場合の対策は書いてあったのですがMacOSを使っている場合にはどのように設定すればよいかがわかりませんでした。

どのように設定すれば新規ウィンドウを開かずに既存のEmacsで開くことができるのでしょうか？

Answer (score -1):

emacsclientを使用すれば、お望みの動作になると思います。
設定方法はググるとたくさん出てきますのでお好みでどうぞ。

http://syohex.hatenablog.com/entry/20101224/1293206906

Comment: -1: emacsclient は emacs デーモンを常駐させた上でエディタを多重起動するための仕組みであり、少なくとも私の環境ではこれを用いても問題は解決されませんでした。

Comment: デーモンを使わなくても、起動したemacsをサーバとして動作させることができます（デーモン機能のほうが後で実装されています）。emacs起動時にserver-startしておけば、立ち上げたemacsがサーバとして動作するので、その状態でemacsclientで接続に行けば、立ち上がっているemacsで開く動作になります。

Comment: はい、それは理解しているのですが、それでも「新規ウィンドウを開く」ことになりませんでしょうか？（私の環境ではそうなったのですが……）

Comment: 今立ち上がっているemacsで動作はするけれど、ウィンドウ（フレーム）が別に立ち上がる、ということですね。Macの場合ですと、ビルドによってことなるかもしれませんが、私の環境ですと`(setq ns-pop-up-frames nil)`で、新しいフレームを使わないようになります。

Comment: それを回答に追記するのは如何でしょうか？